# Javascript Searching Strings Using Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am attempting to complete 2 tasks using Regular Expression -- one function to search for a second string in the first string, and another function to replace all occurrences of a value of the second string in the first string.  The user enters the strings into a textbox and clicks a button to have the results read back in a paragraph.

```
function searchStrings() {
    var searchexp1 = document.getElementById("req1string1").value;
    var searchexp2 = document.getElementById("req1string2").value;
    var patt = new RegExp("searchexp2");
    var res = patt.test("searchexp1");

    if (res === true) {
        document.getElementById("req1result").innerHTML = "We found a match!";
    } else if (res === false) {
        document.getElementById("req1result").innerHTML = "Sorry, those strings don't match.";
    } 
}

function replaceString() {
    var searchexp1 = document.getElementById("req2string1").value;
    var searchexp2 = document.getElementById("req2string2").value;
    var str = document.getElementById("req2string1").innerHTML;
    var res = str.replace("searchexp1"/g , "searchexp2");

    document.getElementById("req2result").innerHTML = res;
}
```

Neither is working and I can't figure out why from the tutorials I used.  What am I missing?

Comment: `var res = str.replace("searchexp1"/g , "searchexp2");` to `var res = str.replace("searchexp1" , "searchexp2",'g');`

Comment: You have a typo, it should be "Sorry., those string", rather than "Sorry, those strings.

Comment: Pranav - I tried your suggestion but am still getting no result when I refresh my page.

Comment: Arjun -- The words somehow got cut off when I posted the question.  In my editor it's " "Sorry, those strings don't match."; "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`replace` accepts a `regex` pattern as the pattern to replace. A `RegExp` accepts modifiers as a second parameter. So you could do:

```
new RegExp(yourVariable, 'g');
```

and then include that as the pattern in the `replace` call.

Additionally, you probably want to remove the quotes from around your variable names (that store the values in the text boxes). This way you will actually be using the values they contain, instead of their names (as Strings).

```
new RegExp(yourVariable);
```

and not

```
new RegExp("yourVariable");
```

Also, assuming

```
var str = document.getElementById("req2string1").innerHTML;
```

is setting `str` to the value of an **inputBox** you should use `.value` instead of `.innerHTML`

```
var str = document.getElementById("req2string1").value;
```

```js
function searchStrings() {
    var searchexp1 = document.getElementById("req1string1").value;
    var searchexp2 = document.getElementById("req1string2").value;
    var patt = new RegExp(searchexp2);
    var output;
    if (patt.test(searchexp1)) {
        output = "We found a match!";
    } else {
        output = "Sorry, those strings don't match.";
    }
    document.getElementById("req1result").innerHTML = output;
}
function replaceString() {
    var searchexp2 = new RegExp(document.getElementById("req2string2").value, 'g');
    var searchexp3 = document.getElementById("req2string3").value;
    var str = document.getElementById("req2string1").value;
    document.getElementById("req2result").innerHTML = str.replace(searchexp2, searchexp3);
}
```

```css
.button {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="req1result"></div></br>
<span>String:</span>
<input id="req1string1" type"text"/>
<span>Pattern:</span>
<input id="req1string2" type="text"/></br>
<span class="button" onclick="searchStrings();">Search</span></br>
<div id="req2result"></div></br>
<span>String:</span>
<input id="req2string1" type"text"/>
<span>Pattern:</span>
<input id="req2string2" type="text"/>
<span>Replace with:</span>
<input id="req2string3" type="text"/></br>
<span class="button" onclick="replaceString();">Replace</span>
```

Comment: Thank you, Moishe.  That was a very thorough and great answer.  It worked perfectly.